# RSpec when to use it should respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have two models linked together by a `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationship as shown below.

```
Class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to my_model
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many other_models
end
```

I now have the respective tests to verify that they have the correct relationship shown below.

```
RSpec.describe MyModel, type: :model do
  it {should have_many(:other_models)}
  it {should respond_to(:other_models)}
end

RSpec.describe OtherModel, type: :model do
  it {should have_many(:my_model)}
  it {should respond_to(:my_model)}
end
```

For this relationship, is the `respond_to` required, and if so why? What does it check for that the have_many does not already check for? If the `respond_to` is not needed in this case, when is an appropriate time to use it? From my current understanding `have_many` already verifies that the field exists, and thus obsoletes the `respond_to` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you are absolutely correct. `respond_to` is not needed as long as you use `should have_many` and `should belong_to`. Your code could just look like this

```
RSpec.describe MyModel, type: :model do
  it {should have_many(:other_models)}
end

RSpec.describe OtherModel, type: :model do
  it {should belong_to(:my_model)}
end
```

You can also take a look at this [list of RSpec Shoulda matchers](http://matchers.shoulda.io/docs/v3.0.0/).

The best time to use `respond_to` is when you include a module into a class and you want to make sure that the class has a certain method. Example:

```
Class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RandomModule
  has_many other_models
end

module RandomModule
  def random_calculation
    3 * 5
  end
end

RSpec.describe MyModel, type: :model do
  it {should have_many(:other_models)}
  it {should respond_to(:random_calculation)}
end
```